# Data is stored but when database shutdown/restart, data is missing

Tags: mysql, database, cluster-computing

I have problem with my database. I using mysql cluster to operate it. Mysql cluster has 1 management node and 3 data & SQL nodes. The databases is load balanced by haproxy and there 2 load balancers is failovered by keepalived. Here list of IPs:

```
192.168.1.11: virtual ip for failover
192.168.1.12: load balancer master
192.168.1.13: load balancer backup
192.168.1.14: data & SQL node 1
192.168.1.15: data & SQL node 2
192.168.1.16: data & SQL node 3
192.168.1.17: management node
```

The problem is when web server(php webpage) connect to database through 192.168.1.11 or direct to database ex: 192.168.1.14 data is stored and when check with heidiSQL data is stored too in database, but the problem come when I shutdown or restart database server and when start it again data that already stored in database is missing. I don't know what the problem is, so what I must to do? Thank's for your attention guys :D

Comment: Are you sure that the data is being commtted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All databases normally don't autocommit your data.
Your data is stored temporarily,and normally afterwards,only after your data is COMMITTED,does your database actually make the changes.
SQL would require you to type the keyword COMMIT.